# Error when adding a source

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install openFOAM, but the installation requires that I first run the lines:

```
VERS=$(lsb_release -cs) 
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu $VERS main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam.list"
```

And then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

When I run this last line I however get the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I havent seen anyone else complaining about this when installing openFOAM, so I don't think it is a fault with openFOAM

Comment: Someone has to be the first. ;) Have you seen reports of this method working on Trusty specifically?

Comment: @fkraiem, I am new to ubuntu and was under the impression that I was running 12.04 LTS, but must have updated without knowing it. Is  there a way of reverting back to 12.04? I would rather stay on the LTS version.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I mean 14.04, not 12.04! OpenFOAM is not out on 14.04 yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OpenFOAM download page](http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php), the currently available versions do not include Ubuntu Trusty Tahr:

> OpenFOAM and Paraview are currently available for the following versions of Ubuntu:
>
> - 12.04 LTS, codename precise
> - 12.10, codename quantal
> - 13.04, codename raring
> - 13.10, codename saucy

Comment: O yes I see, I did actually see that when installing, but got confused with 12.04 and 14.04. Thanks